# Is there a way to find out if a supplied password matches an actual password for a particular user?

Tags: c, linux, macos, go, bsd

I have an application that reads a user's name and password over a socket.  I want to determine if the supplied password matches the password that the OS has for that user. If it does, I want to fork a process running as that user. Ideally, the code would be in Go, but I can do C if needed.  Ideally, it would work in Linux, OSX, and BSD.

Comment: try this library maybe: https://godoc.org/github.com/msteinert/pam

Comment: Thank you, it looks promising.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I tried  godoc.org/github.com/msteinert/pam on my Mac, doesn't work.  I ran test as root and they all fail with a system error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PAM Authentication for both linux and OS X.
The main function being [pam_authenticate](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_authenticate), though you'll need to start the pam service first and end it when you're finished.

[Here's an example](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-example.html) of its basic usage.

Comment: I ended up writing a cgo module that uses PAM. There are some differences between BSD (Mac) and Linux but it's not that big of a deal.
https://github.com/murphybytes/ucp/tree/master/pam